# Verify whether searching string is present or not before taking action-python

Tags: python

Verify whether searching string is present or not before taking action-python

```
s = '''
:20:name
:21A:Address
:22B:phone
:57A:/256789422254
TEST VALUE
:59B:/REST_MA
LINE1
:59C:TEST
'''
```

Expected result:

value of `a:256789`

value of `b:TEST VALUE`

code written:

```
a, b = s[s.index(':57A:') - 1 :].strip().split("\n")[:2]
a = a.split(':')[2]
print("value of A:" + a[1:7])
print("value of B:" + b)
```

what I need:?

If :57A: is not present then its throwing error.

Error details:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 12, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found
```

Expected:
instead of throwing error , just need to print 'null' or something meaningfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to check for the membership and act accordingly:

```
if ':57A:' in s:
    a, b = s[s.index(':57A:') - 1 :].strip().split("\n")[:2]
    a = a.split(':')[2]
    print("value of A:" + a[1:7])
    print("value of B:" + b)
else:
    print('not found')  # or other meaningful message.
```